# Using Viewcontroller to control tabbarController

Tags: uiactionsheet, viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to use an ActionSheet (via a viewcontroller which is an item of the tabbarcontroller) to access another tab. But I don't seem to be able to do that.

Here is the scenario:
1. I click Tab 3
2. Actionsheet initiated 
3. I click 'Cancel'
4. [here is what I want] - bring me back to tab 1.

How do i actually get 4 to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following

```
[[self tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:0];
```

You set the number according to which tab you want to go to